# SWT DragDetected event for ScrolledComposite

Tags: java, swt

What EventListeners are supported by ScrolledComposite in order to catch a scroll action event?

Answer (score 1):

Since `ScrolledComposite` extends `Scrollable` you can call `getVerticalBar()` and `getHorizontalBar()` to get the vertical and horizontal `ScrollBar` instances.

You can then call `addSelectionListener` on the scroll bar to get an event on any change to the scrolling. The Javadoc for this says:

> When widgetSelected is called, the event object detail field contains
> one of the following values: SWT.NONE - for the end of a drag.
> SWT.DRAG. SWT.HOME. SWT.END. SWT.ARROW_DOWN. SWT.ARROW_UP.
> SWT.PAGE_DOWN. SWT.PAGE_UP.